# Java's LocalDateTime field doesn't match precision in JUnit test

Tags: java, jooq, java-17, junit-jupiter

I have some unit tests that run fine under `Java 11.x` and a `Docker` container with `PostgreSQL 12.x`. I'm in the process of migrating the application into `Java 17.x`, and now there are several of these unit tests failing. As far as I can tell the issue is around the precision of `LocalDateTime` types.

```bash
[ERROR]   UnitTest.test1:334
expected: CustomType (3185, 1, Description, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.924910854, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.924951801, user, false)
 but was: CustomType (3185, 1, Description, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.924911, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.924952, user, false)
[ERROR]   UnitTest.test2:60
expected: CustomType2 (3182, Test, Hello, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.653447384, user, index, null, null, false, null)
 but was: CustomType2 (3182, Test, Hello, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.653447, user, index, null, null, false, null)
[ERROR]   UnitTest.test3:268
expected: CustomType (3184, 1, Description, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.863401246, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.863438735, user, false)
 but was: CustomType (3184, 1, Description, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.863401, 2022-12-01T22:10:27.863439, user, false)
```

The tests are simple: the auto-generated (`jOOQ`) objects are compared after being instantiated manually with some predefined data (the `expected`), and then saved/updated from the database (the `actual`). The types in the database are defined as `timestamp` and `jOOQ` generates a `LocalDateTime` (instead of an `Instant` I would say) for the same.

```java
// Unit Test
CustomType instance = CustomType.builder()
    // ...rest of the fields ommited for brevity
    .lastUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime.now())
    .build();

CustomType result = repository.insert(instance);
instance.setId(result.getId());
Assertions.assertThat(result).isEqualTo(instance); // AssertJ
```

```java
// Repository
public CustomType insert(CustomType data) {
  data.setId(null);
  CustomTypeRecord record = new CustomTypeRecord(); // ...nevermind using record here ;)
  record.from(data);
  data = mainDsl.insertInto(CUSTOM_TYPE)
      .set(record)
      .returning()
      .fetchOneInto(CustomType.class);
  return data;
}
```

I don't know where else to look for hint(s) of what's going on here. I'm certain there aren't any custom formatting done to the `LocalDateTime` types in the source code.

---

#### UPDATES

Dependencies after upgrading `jOOQ` to version `3.17.5`:

```bash
$ ./mvnw dependency:list
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:list (default-cli) @ graphql-api ---
[INFO]
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq:jar:2.7.4:compile -- module spring.boot.starter.jooq [auto]
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.4:compile -- module spring.boot.starter.jdbc [auto]
[INFO]    com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile -- module com.zaxxer.hikari
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.23:compile -- module spring.jdbc [auto]
[INFO]    jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile -- module jakarta.activation
[INFO]    jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile -- module java.xml.bind
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.23:compile -- module spring.tx [auto]
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.23:compile -- module spring.core [auto]
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.23:compile -- module spring.jcl [auto]
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.17.5:compile -- module org.jooq
[INFO]    io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:jar:0.9.1.RELEASE:compile -- module r2dbc.spi [auto]
[INFO]    org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile -- module org.reactivestreams [auto]
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq-codegen:jar:3.17.5:compile -- module org.jooq.codegen
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:3.17.5:compile -- module org.jooq.meta
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq-postgres-extensions:jar:3.17.5:compile -- module org.jooq.postgres.extensions
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.4:compile -- module spring.boot.starter.web [auto]
...
```

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version `3.16.6`. A peculiarity with this project is that the `jOOQ` tables and POJOs are manually auto-generated beforehand and stored in the repository, along with the source code.

Comment: Can you try upgrading? This was fixed in 3.18.0, 3.17.4, 3.16.10: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13919. Many other issues have been fixed as well since 3.16.6...

Comment: Sure, I can definitely try that! Let me do the upgrade, regenerate everything, and will post the outcome here. Thanks for the tip, Lukas.

Comment: I did upgrade `jOOQ` to version `3.17.5` and regenerated everything. I can see now that `DefaultCatalog` has `REQUIRE_RUNTIME_JOOQ_VERSION = Constants.VERSION_3_17` and some minor enhancements in the files. Still, I'm getting the same errors with the precision in the timestamps. I've also checked (just in case) the effective `POM` with `./mvnw help:effective-pom` and the versions are correct. I'm excluding `org.jooq:jooq` from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq`, but as far as I can tell, redefining it should do the same — which I'm doing as well.

Comment: @LukasEder FYI ... The OP missed tagging you.